# Getting type errors of cannot read property 'contacted' and 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vuejs and I am trying to develop a form and my browser went blank when I began to develop this code in User.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="users">
    <h1>Users</h1>
    <form v-on:submit="addUser">
      <input type="text" v-model="newUser.name" placeholder="Enter Name">
      <br />
      <input type="text" v-model="newUser.email" placeholder="Enter Email">
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li vi-for="user in users">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" v-model="user.contacted">
        <span :class="{contacted: user.contacted}">
          {{user.name}}: {{user.email}}
        </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'users',
    data() {
      return {
        newUser: {},
        users: [
          {
            name: 'Brad Traversy',
            email: 'techguy@gmail.com',
            contacted: false
          },
          {
          name: 'Hendrik John',
          email: 'hjohn@gmail.com',
          contacted: false
          },
          {
          name: 'Brooke Dukes',
          email: 'bdukes@automattic.com',
          contacted: false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      addUser: function(e){
        this.users.push({
          name: this.newUser.name,
          email: this.newUser.email,
          contacted: false
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    },
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .contacted{
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
</style>
```

I seem to be getting Cannot read property of undefined for the properties inside the users array, but I have been unable to figure out why.

Comment: `v-for` not `vi-for`.

Comment: I so wish these errors would be more clear. I know I should probably keep syntax errors in mind, but when the error is saying something is undefined, I am looking for where and how I am supposed to define it, as opposed to "oh I must have made a syntax error somewhere" Annoying, anyway, please post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple syntax error here:

```
<li vi-for="user in users">
```

Should be

```
<li v-for="user in users">
```

FWIW, I expect the error was along the lines of "can't read the property `contacted` of undefined" which is a javascript error indicating that `user` is undefined. Then you just look at where `user` *should* be defined to find your error.

Comment: And in this case, user should have been defined at <li v-for="user in users">. Thank you Bert, this is helpful.